# when is it true that $x^\prime \Pi \mathbf{1}+ \mathbf{1}^\prime \Pi^\prime x = 2x^\prime \Pi \mathbf{1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $x^\prime$ be a $1 \times n$ vector , $\Pi$ be a $n\times n$ matrix, 
and $\mathbf{1}^\prime\ $ be a $1 \times n$ vector of 1's. When is it true
that $x^\prime \Pi \mathbf{1}+ \mathbf{1}^\prime \Pi^\prime x = 2x^\prime \Pi \mathbf{1}$. For example,if $\Pi$ is a $2 \times 2$ symmetric matrix then:
$
[x_{1} , x_{2}]
\begin{bmatrix}
       \pi_{1} & \pi_{2} \\
       \pi_{2} & \pi_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
       1 \\
       1
\end{bmatrix}
+
[1 , 1]
\begin{bmatrix}
       \pi_{1} & \pi_{2} \\
       \pi_{2} & \pi_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
[x_{1} , x_{2}]^\prime
= 2 x_1 (\pi_1 + \pi_2) + x_2 (\pi_2 + \pi_3) = 2x^\prime \Pi \mathbf{1}
$

But in general ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why put the same term on $x'\Pi\mathbf1$ on both sides without cancelling? You are just asking whether $x'\Pi\mathbf1=\mathbf1'\Pi'x$, and since both sides are transposes of each other, and $1\times1$ matrices, which are always symmetric, this is true. Even $x'A'y=y'Ax$ holds true whenever $x,y$ are one-column matrices, for the same reason.

Comment: of course. Thanks.